# How to change the button text of show/hide or spoiler button while on click in html , in the following code

Tags: html

I want to change the text of the Show/hide button or spoiler button while on click by users. In default condition the button text is written as Show and when user click the button the button text should replace with Hide and again if the user click on Hide the button text should change to Show. How to do that,please anyone help me and i will be very thankful.

```html
<button title="Click to Show/Hide Content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">Show/Hide</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
  ADD YOUR HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/Hide button without reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971580/show-hide-button-without-reload-page)

Comment: What have you tried already to make the text change?

Comment: Without using javascript and jquery is it not possible ?Because for certain case i dont want to use javascript /jquery . @MartinParkin

Comment: @KatrinaPathak It's _not possible_ without using some JavaScript.  In your example you have used JavaScript already.  The answers already provided will achieve what you are looking for

Comment: Sir, I am trying to do this blogger blogspot but it is not working @MartinParkin

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure `JavaScript` or `Jquery` to handle this.

**In Pure Javascript:**

You can define a method and check the element style property. and also `style.display` is attribute that you should check.

The below code
solve your problem:

```
<script>
    function toggle(){
        var spolier = document.getElementById('spoiler');

        if(spolier.style.display == "none"){
            spolier.style.display= "block";
        }
        else {
            spolier.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
<button title="Click to Show"  type="button" onclick="toggle()">Show</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
ADD YOUR HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

**In Jquery:**

You should check `attr` attribute in jquery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    function toggle(){
      if ($('#spolier').attr("display") == "none"){
         $('#spolier').attr('display', 'block');
      } else{
         $('#spolier').attr('display', 'none');
      }
    }
</script>


<button title="Click to Show"  type="button" onclick="toggle()">Show</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
ADD YOUR HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Not working in html @Siavash Ghanbari, Without using javascript and jquery is it not possible ?Because for certain case i dont want to use javascript /jquery .

Comment: Sir, I am trying to do this blogger blogspot but it is not working @Siavash Ghanbari

Comment: first of all jQuery is optional, but you have to use JavaScript, and this code worked, I test it before post here. and finally there is no another way and I don't know why people gave down-vote to this answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

Without jquery:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toggle)

function toggle(event) {
  if (document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display == 'none') {
    event.target.innerText = 'Hide'
    document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display = ''
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = 'Show'
    document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<button title="Click to Show/Hide Content" type="button">Show</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
  ADD YOUR HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to do this blogger blogspot but it is not working @Smollet777

Comment: So you you have many `<div id="spoiler">` with corresponding buttons. Am i right?
You need to add listener to each button then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```js
$(function(){
   var button = true;
   $('button').on('click', function(){
      if ($('button').text().indexOf('Show') > -1){
         $(this).text('Hide');
      } else{
         $(this).text('Show');
      }
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button title="Click to Show/Hide Content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">Show</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
ADD YOUR HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Without using javascript and jquery is it not possible ?Because for certain case i dont want to use javascript /jquery .

Comment: For this you need to use checkbox workaround for without js and jquery approach.

Comment: See this, and you'll understand it...https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-show-moreless-functionality-with-pure-css/

Comment: Sir, I am trying to do this blogger blogspot but it is not working @CodeGator

Comment: Can you share the URL you're talking about?